# How do you pass input value into a function on form submit in Angular 6?

Tags: javascript, angular

So my code works when I hit enter (it runs the `performSearch` function successfully), but when I try to run the function by hitting my submit button I get the error:

> cannot read property error of undefined

**Here's my code:**

```
<mat-form-field (ngSubmit)='performSearch($event)' color='primary' id='search-input' class='full-width' appearance='outline'>
    <mat-label color='red'>Search</mat-label>
    <input #searchBar matInput  [(ngModel)]='searchValue' name='searchBar' [value]='searchValue' (keyup.enter)='performSearch($event)'>
 </mat-form-field>

 <button mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)='performSearch(searchBar.value)' id='submit-search' type='submit' for='searchBar'>Submit</button>
```

All I want is a way to grab the `#searchBar`' value and pass it into the `performSearch()` function that fires when I click the button. How do I do that?

Comment: Your input contains modal named `searchValue` you should pass the same when clicking the submit button.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are doing two way binding in the search bar with `var searchValue` so you need to change only pass this var on click of submit.
Just replace your click event

```
(click)='performSearch(searchBar.value)' to
(click)='performSearch(searchValue)'
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are working with a piece that needs to pass it's own value into a method, this will do the trick:

```
<input type="number" value="{{myValue}}" (change)="updateMyValue($event.target.value)">
```

Answer (score 2):

This is because you are sending the event object on form submit, so you'll get the complete Event object.

```
(ngSubmit)='performSearch($event)'
```

If you just want one value, use your template reference variable of input as you are using in click event,

```
(ngSubmit)='performSearch(searchBar.value)'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 (click)="performSearch(searchValue)"
```

It will work, because you've model in searchbar input, it will send that value through click function!