# Input in ngFor list with action when clicking on button

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I have a list that requires `ngFor`, so far so good, each item needs an `input` with a `button` that does something with the value of the input.

```
<mat-list role="list">
  <mat-list-item *ngFor="let item of items">{{item}}: 

    <mat-form-field>
      <input matInput>
    </mat-form-field>
    <button mat-stroked-button (click)="addCookie()">Add Cookie</button>

  </mat-list-item>
</mat-list>
```

Check https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lpiakc?file=app%2Flist-overview-example.ts

How can I pass the value of the input to the method `addCookie`?

```
export class ListOverviewExample {
  items = ['item 1', 'item 2', 'item 3'];

  addCookie() {
    console.log("here I would like to paste the value of the input field");
  }
}
```

Comment: check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50806610/how-do-you-pass-input-value-into-a-function-on-form-submit-in-angular-6/50811039) out

Comment: @Vega i think he meant to say the value of the input

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamic template reference variable inside ngFor (Angular 2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44440879/dynamic-template-reference-variable-inside-ngfor-angular-2)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this by using `#input` in your html then you can pass the value of that input into the `addCookie` function.

```
<mat-list role="list">
  <mat-list-item *ngFor="let item of items">{{item}}:
    <mat-form-field>
      <input matInput #input>
    </mat-form-field>
    <button mat-stroked-button (click)="addCookie(input.value)">Add Cookie</button>
  </mat-list-item>
</mat-list>
```

Comment: That's it! Can you explain why that even works. I thought about that, but then I thought I'd be declaring `#input` multiple times

Comment: According to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48348156/7391435) it is uniques because you use it inside the loop.